# mulitiple indexes are being deleted. but I only want the index selected to be deleted Flutter, dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to delete a specific ExtraItem when the "Delete" Flatbutton is pressed. Everything seems in terms of the index being deleted. But, it also deletes/clears other previously added text from the UI (which I do not want). How do I fix the clearing of all other previously added text?

Test case 1
before deletion of index 0: [before deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEHtS.png)
after deletion of index 0: [after deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzibB.png)

Test case 2
before deletion of index 1: [before deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P35to.png)
after deletion of index 1: [after deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvNNY.png)

Here is my code, in other for reproduction

```
class ExtraItem extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isLast = false;
  final VoidCallback onExtraAdded;
  final VoidCallback onNameChanged;
  final VoidCallback onPriceChanged;
  final VoidCallback onDeleteClicked;
  final ExtraItem extra;
  String name;

  int price;
  int index;
  ExtraItem({
    Key key,
    this.isLast,
    this.onExtraAdded,
    this.extra,
    this.index,
    this.onNameChanged,
    this.onPriceChanged,
    this.onDeleteClicked,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExtraItemState createState() => _ExtraItemState();
}

class _ExtraItemState extends State<ExtraItem> {
  String type;

  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController priceController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    nameController.dispose();
    priceController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _showExtrasDialog() async {
    await showDialog<String>(
      context: this.context,
      child: new _SystemPadding(
        child: new AlertDialog(
          title: Text(
            'Modify Extras ',
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Montserrat Medium", fontSize: 15),
          ),
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          content: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[],
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
                child: const Text('CANCEL'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(this.context);
                }),
            new FlatButton(
                child: const Text('ADD EXTRA'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    widget.onExtraAdded();
                  });
                  Navigator.pop(this.context);
                }),
            //this is also for the modal
            new FlatButton(
                child: const Text('REMOVE'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    widget.onDeleteClicked();
                  });
                  Navigator.pop(this.context);
                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, top: 5),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                width: 144,
                height: 49,
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                child: Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                    child: TextField(
                      autofocus: true,
                      controller: nameController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        print("changing");
                        widget.name = value;
                        widget.onNameChanged();
                      },
                      scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                width: 1, color: Color(0xff2E2E2E))),
                        isDense: true,
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                width: 1, color: Color(0xffDEDEDE))),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                width: 144,
                height: 49,
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                child: Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                    child: TextField(
                      autofocus: true,
                      controller: priceController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        print("changing");
                        widget.price = int.parse(value);
                        widget.onPriceChanged();
                      },
                      scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "\$",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: sankaraGreyColor,
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat Medium",
                            fontSize: 15),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                width: 1, color: Color(0xff2E2E2E))),
                        isDense: false,
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                width: 1, color: Color(0xffDEDEDE))),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // widget.isLast
            //     ?
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 20,
                      height: 20,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text("+",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: "Montserrat Medium",
                                fontSize: 15,
                                color: sankaraGreyColor)),
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          border: Border.all(color: Color(0xffDEDEDE))),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _showExtrasDialog();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                    child: Text(
                      "Modify",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "Montserrat Medium", fontSize: 7),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
            // : Padding(
            //     padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
            //     child: Column(
            //       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            //       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            //       children: [
            //         Container(
            //           width: 20,
            //           height: 20,
            //         ),
            //       ],
            //     ),
            //   )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This where the interactions happen

```
class ThirdPage extends StatefulWidget {
  Function(List<ExtraItem>) onExtrasChanged;
  Function(List<ExtraItem>) onDrinksChanged;
  Function(List<ExtraItem>) onSidesChanged;
  Function(int) onExtrasRemoved;

  ThirdPage(
      {this.onExtrasChanged,
      this.onDrinksChanged,
      this.onSidesChanged,
      this.onExtrasRemoved});

  @override
  _ThirdPageState createState() => _ThirdPageState();
}

class _ThirdPageState extends State<ThirdPage> {
  List<ExtraItem> extras = [];
  List<ExtraItem> drinks = [];
  List<ExtraItem> sides = [];

  void addDrinksItem() {
    print("adding drink");
    for (int i = 0; i < drinks.length; i++) {
      setState(() {
        drinks[i].isLast = false;
      });
    }
    setState(() {
      drinks.add(ExtraItem(
        onExtraAdded: () {
          addDrinksItem();
        },
        onNameChanged: () {
          widget.onDrinksChanged(drinks);

          printDrinkValues();
        },
        onPriceChanged: () {
          widget.onDrinksChanged(drinks);

          printDrinkValues();
        },
        isLast: true,
        index: drinks.length,
      ));
    });
  }



  void _deleteItem(int index) {
    print(index);
    setState(() {
     extras.removeAt(index);
     });
    
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    addExtraItem();
    addDrinksItem();
    addSidesItem();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            print(extras[0].isLast);
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 380,
            height: 600,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                border: Border.all(color: Color(0xffECECEC))),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 0, top: 30),
              child: ListView(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      printExtraValues();
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "Customize your menu",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "Montserrat Medium",
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 20),
                    child: Text(
                      "Include any add-ons, if any",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "Montserrat Regular",
                          fontSize: 12,
                          color: sankaraGreyColor),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      "Mealbox item as extra",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "Montserrat Medium",
                          fontSize: 12,
                          color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 144,
                        child: Text(
                          "Name",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "Montserrat Medium",
                              fontSize: 10,
                              color: sankaraGreyColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 16,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 144,
                        child: Text(
                          "Price Per Item",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "Montserrat Medium",
                              fontSize: 10,
                              color: sankaraGreyColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: extras.length,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        int ind = index;
                        final extra = extras[index];
                        return ExtraItem(
                          key: ObjectKey(extra),
                          extra: extras[index],
                          onExtraAdded: () => addExtraItem(),
                          onDeleteClicked: () => _deleteItem(ind),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: when you press delete how many time it print index ?

Comment: @Akshay Nayka it only prints the index once

Comment: i'm not sure but try to call the delete function like this  `onDeleteClicked: (){ _deleteItem(ind) },`